# How to determine which parts of user input should be converted into a link like Stack Overflow does?

Tags: javascript, string, url, hyperlink

Stackoverflow.com somehow detects certain text as links and converts it, for example:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip or<br>
https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:关于中文维基百科/en
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_(disambiguation)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987894/as-of-may-15-2017-what-characters-are-arent-allowed-in-a-web-address-as-typed
```

is displayed to you, dear reader, as:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) or
[https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:关于中文维基百科/en](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E5%85%B3%E4%BA%8E%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E7%BB%B4%E5%9F%BA%E7%99%BE%E7%A7%91/en)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_(disambiguation)

[As of May 15, 2017, what characters are/aren't allowed in a web address as typed/pasted by a user (preferably in regex form)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987894/as-of-may-15-2017-what-characters-are-arent-allowed-in-a-web-address-as-typed)

How would someone implement a similar system (that respects intellectual property rights in the event that the particular algorithm used by this site is proprietary)?

I'm looking for something that can handle all of the above cases. Bonus points if it goes above and beyond and correctly handles https://❤❤❤.ws/ which this site unfortunately does not.

Also note:
    `http://<IFRAME SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');"></IFRAME>`
became http:// So avoiding unsafe html is important.

Comment: Just use any algorithm that matches parts of text that look like URIs. A regex engine might help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

User regular expression to match strings starting with `https://` to first white space and replace with replacement pattern.

```js
var str = "http://❤❤❤.ws/";
var link = str.replace(/(http(|s):\/\/[^<\s]*)/, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
document.write(link);
```

Fetch title. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` policy applies.

```
fetch(link.match(/http:[^ ]+/))

.then(response => {
    return response.text()
})

.then(body => {
    document.write(body.match(/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/)[1]);
});
```

[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: good try, but that's not what he's looking for. he want to achieve some information about that URL, like the page's title, for example, and replace de code `{URL}` with `<a href="{URL}">{title}</a>`. You're on the way!

Comment: @KikoGarcia I don't see that. Getting the page title is some extra feature that even SO does only for some internal URIs.

Comment: Yep, the algorithm must respect that. He took four cases for his problem and want a single algorithm to match it all. The internal URL case is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987894/as-of-may-15-2017-what-characters-are-arent-allowed-in-a-web-address-as-typed - Just typed `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987894/as-of-may-15-2017-what-characters-are-arent-allowed-in-a-web-address-as-typed`

Comment: If I'm reading that regex correctly, you're accepting any character that is not a space, which essentially means that anything that begins with http:// will become a link until the user hits space. Right?

Comment: It extracts string starting with `http://` or `https://` up to the first space from input string.

Comment: There are some other characters that should probably be rejected in there: The control characters (chars 0-1F and 7F), including new line, tab, and carriage return.
 "<>\^`{|} These are forbidden in a url.

Comment: But you get the idea. I wasn't trying to write a complete solution.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind updating your answer to reflect those character exceptions, I would happily accept it as the answer such that others can take advantage of it.

Comment: _"I wasn't trying to write a complete solution"_ Why not?

Comment: `[^<\s]*` match to tag start or any white space character.